# Given an array of $N$ integers in which the first $n$ of them are positive and the rest are negative, can we find $n$ in O(log$n$) time?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

Binary search will find $n$ in O(log$N$) time, is there a way to do it in O(log$n$) time?


I was thinking on the lines: 
Check every $2^i$th number till you encounter a negative integer. If, at the $k$th step we encounter a negative integer, perform the same procedure starting from the $2^{k−1}$th number. 
However, I'm not sure of the time complexity of this algorithm.

Comment: First I was sceptical, but in fact, this method finds the "turning point" quickly, if $n$ is small. I am not sure however whether it is actually $O(\log(n))$ , but I am optimistic it is.

Comment: How could it not depend on $N$. For everything you have in mind check the limit $N\to\infty$.For instance your "check every $2^î$th number" would diverge for finite $n$.

Comment: Won't converge after a while? Say it encounters a negative integer at index 8, it will then perform the same procedure between indices 4 and 8, and so on for successive iterations.

Comment: @Its_me We do not have to check every such point. Only until we find a negative entry. So, no matter how large $N$ is, we find the answer quickly, if , lets say , $n$ is $20$. Note that we know that there are only positives upto some point and then only negatives.

Comment: @Peter: I see, you  treat $N$ as a fixed constant. Otherwise, if you consider $n$ and $N$ as variables then the  [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) would be incorrect.

Comment: @Its_me No, $N$ is not fixed, for a fixed $n$ , we need an effort only depending on $n$ . $N$ can be , lets say , Graham's number. But to find a reasonable small "turning point" , the number $n$ , can nevertheless be done efficiently. So, the effort does not grow with $N$, only with $n$.

Comment: @Peter: Isn't it that for multiple variables $(n,N)$ a function $f(n,N)$ is $O(\log n)$ iff $\exists\,M\,\exists\,C > 0~\text{ such that for all } (n,N) \text{ with }~n \ge M, |f(n,N)| \le C\,|\log(n)|$. So $f$ cannot be function of $N$. Isn't it?

Comment: The structure of the problem here leads to an independence of $N$ (we only need to have at least $n$ elements that the property can hold at all). Therefore , the computational complexity is here only a function of $n$ , and I think, it actually is $O(\log(n))$ , I am just not quite sure.

Comment: What does your algorithm do if the $2^i$-th number is positive, and the $2^{i+1}$-th number is either out of range or already checked?

Comment: @Servaes If $n$ is very small and $N$ huge this would be very inefficient.

Comment: @Servaes In the case, we are out of range, we can then continue with a usual binary search with the rest of the interval. And in this case, $n$ exceeds $\frac{N}{2}$ , hence, if $N$ is huge, $n$ is it as well.

Comment: @Peter I see, thanks.

Comment: It seems that this is $O(\log(n)^2)$ by considering what happens if $n=2^k-1$. I haven't checked rigorously yet though.

Comment: @Servaes As soon as we have found an upper bound for the turning point $n$ (which can at most be $2n$ because of our search strategy) , we can continue with a usual binary search for an array with at most $2n$ entries , so I think, it is $O(\log(n))$

Comment: @Peter I agree. In my last comment, I was considering the algorithm described in the quesion body.